# How can I fix this table? It flexes both side ways and front to back

Tags: tabletop, stability

The table doesn't wobble; it flexes in any direction you move it. Any slight contact causes this. I'm not sure if it's because the two legs are way too thin.
 [image: overall view]
[image: underside view]

---

Merged and cleaned up from additional info originally posted as an answer:

The top is attached to the frame with 6 plastic nails & expanders. The frame is the one that is flexing. The connection between the support frame and the legs is not welded.

[image: underside view 1]

[image: underside view 2]

[image: underside view 3]

[image: underside view 4]

Comment: How is the table top attached to the frame? Does the frame flex or is it just the top?

Comment: This does not look to be a woodworking issue. I suspect the connection between the support frame and the leg is not rigid enough.  Anything less than a welded connection will be problematic.  If that is the case, then there is not much to be done woodworking wise.

Comment: The flex is \*in* the legs I'm sure so unfortunately you won't be able fix the problem unless you change the legs.

Comment: A quick hack fix would be to splay the legs so that they can't move in the same direction.

Comment: The legs appear to be adjustable in height, so my guess is there is play in the connection between the male and female portion of the legs. If that is the case, you could potentially put some through bolts in them and tighten them down enough to remove that wobble. You will have to narrow down the source of the flexing to make sure it isn't one of the static connections.

Comment: You can ditch the poor metal frame and replace it with four wooden legs and an apron, and that table will be very solid.  If you are interested in pursuing this option (really not very difficult) I or others with better experience can give you more details.